# NDVI from SRGB image

Tags: ndvi

I have a SRGB image from which I need to get the NDVI value.

I know how to calculate the NDVI, but it does not work with this SRGB image.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Could you tell us, which software you're using, what you tried so far and what error comes up, when you calculate the NDVI?

Comment: I have used pix4d to stich image and then license has expired of pix4d. I have used the ERDAS imagine and its has calculated NDVI and range is 0-1, unfortunately that is the wrong way to calculate NDVI from the SRGB image. So i need to calculate the greenness index. My motto is to calculate the biomass using the UAV derived SRGB image.